# Guardar una un ArrayList en una variable

Tags: lista, netbeans, arraylist

Bueno a decir verdad aun soy un poco inexperto pero tengo un problema hice un ArrayList llamado ***lista*** e hice un ciclo for para generar posiciones vacias para despues asignarles los datos remplazandolas con **set.lista(,);** , mi problema radica en que quiero almacenar **lista.add("");** en una variable para que pueda usarla afuera de mi ciclo for pero me marca el error ***boolean cannot be converted to String*** y no encuentro solucion alguna para poder almacenar esto sin tener que convetirla forzosamente en un valor booleano, disculpen si es tonta la pregunta pero la verdad necesito saberlo

```
 String mensaje="";
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
       List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>(i);
       
      mensaje= lista.add("");

    }
    
    mensaje = lista.set(1, "2");
    System.out.println(mensaje);
```

Answer (score 0):

tu error radica en que no puedes asignar una método a una variable por lo que la
asignación

```
mensaje = lista.add("") *ES UN ERROR*
```

ya que lista.add es un método que retorna un valor booleano de la forma en la que la quieres utilizar, puedes consultar la documentación de ArrayList en [ArrayList Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

ahora para resolver esto no es necesario que le asignes una entrada sub-i a tu ArrayList

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)
        
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>;
            
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
              String mensaje= sc.next();
               
              lista.add(mensaje);
        
            }
            
            mensaje = lista.set(1, "2");
            System.out.println(mensaje);
```

Lo que se hace es leer el dato desde la consola, y añadimos ese dato al ArrayList

Saludos!